# можно ли вставлять в цитату свои слова (если да, то как)?

Tags: цитата, цитаты, оформление-цитат

«всё, ***в целом***, улеглось, забылось».

Comment: Оформление вопроса не волнует? Пробелы, точки... Что мешает?

Comment: не волнует. вопрос о другом. точку в конце предложения и пробел в состоянии поставить каждый

Comment: зачем вставлять сюда вводное "в целом".

Comment: мне это нужно для более ясного выражения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Из статьи **[Основные способы цитирования](https://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/313-osnovnyesposobycitirovaniya.html):**

Если цитирующий вставляет в цитату свой текст, поясняющий в ней предложение или отдельные слова, то это пояснение заключается **в квадратные скобки.**

Например: А волоса у нее [русалки] зеленые, что твоя конопля (Т.).

2. Здесь речь идет о **поясняющих** словах. Вероятно, нужно  учитывать назначение слова **"в целом"** в конкретном тексте.
3. В статье есть еще материал:

Если автор подчеркивает **отдельные слова цитаты** для усиления их значения (в печати эти слова выделяются **особым шрифтом**), то он оговаривает это в примечании, заключая его в скобки и указывая свои инициалы, перед которыми ставится тире.

Может, эти варианты можно **совместить**: квадратные скобки и особый шрифт.

Comment: спасибо...правда, немного не то. вот если все же на письме, не в печати? вероятно, так делать просто нельзя 

Comment: Если на письме, то можно и квадратик нарисовать вместо скобок, а на статью сослаться)

Comment: мое «в целом» подойдёт для квадратика? 

Comment: В этом есть элемент авторского оформления, но его можно объяснить. "В целом" – это и вставка, и желание выделить  эту вставку.

Comment: Sharon, если вставляем своё слово в цитату, то квадратных скобок достаточно. А курсив, как сказано, применяется для выделения слов самой цитаты с последующим примечанием в круглых скобках.

Comment: @fleurdellyss  Получается такая запись:  «всё [в целом] улеглось, забылось».

Comment: Любое слово можно вставить? Тогда достаточно скобок. Но вставить - это же не подчеркнуть значимость, а только пояснить. А что мы здесь поясняем? Пусть будет дополнительное пояснение-замечание.

Comment: Sharon, согласен, что указанный пример не подходит для такого разбора. Если автор хочет показать своё отношение к чужим словам, дать им характеристику и пр., то это нужно делать в отдельном сообщении.

Comment: Может, и не хочет. Остановимся на скобках (что-то вроде реплики).

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец спасибо большое!